# What is the right way to execute c# code in a powershell script?

Tags: c#, winforms, powershell

I'm trying to play/pause media and I found some c# code but when I try to implement it into my powershell script, nothing happens... This is what I tried:

```
Add-Type @'
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace UniversalSandbox
{
    public partial class Form1
    {
        public const int KEYEVENTF_EXTENTEDKEY = 1;
        public const int KEYEVENTF_KEYUP = 0;
        public const int VK_MEDIA_NEXT_TRACK = 0xB0;
        public const int VK_MEDIA_PLAY_PAUSE = 0xB3;
        public const int VK_MEDIA_PREV_TRACK = 0xB1;

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern void keybd_event(byte virtualKey, byte scanCode, uint flags, IntPtr extraInfo);





        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            keybd_event(VK_MEDIA_PLAY_PAUSE, 0, KEYEVENTF_EXTENTEDKEY, IntPtr.Zero);
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            keybd_event(VK_MEDIA_PREV_TRACK, 0, KEYEVENTF_EXTENTEDKEY, IntPtr.Zero);
        }

        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            keybd_event(VK_MEDIA_NEXT_TRACK, 0, KEYEVENTF_EXTENTEDKEY, IntPtr.Zero);
        }
    }
}
'@

[UniversalSandbox.Form1]::button1_Click;
```

I call the play/pause event using [UniversalSandbox.Form1]::button1_Click; but nothing happens... Is my syntax wrong?

(I found the c# code [here](https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/128/how-to-play-pause-music-or-go-to-next-and-previous-track-from-windows-using-c-valid-for-all-windows-music-players))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You example is a Windows Forms app. You need to add some extra buttons and create form instance (GUI) and click buttons to manipulate it. button1_click is event you need to assign to the button control (you can't call it directly). Below is updated example.

```bsh
Add-Type @'
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace UniversalSandbox
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public const int KEYEVENTF_EXTENTEDKEY = 1;
        public const int KEYEVENTF_KEYUP = 0;
        public const int VK_MEDIA_NEXT_TRACK = 0xB0;
        public const int VK_MEDIA_PLAY_PAUSE = 0xB3;
        public const int VK_MEDIA_PREV_TRACK = 0xB1;

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern void keybd_event(byte virtualKey, byte scanCode, uint flags, IntPtr extraInfo);

        public Form1()
        {


            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }


        private void InitializeComponent(){
        var button1 = new Button();
        var button2 = new Button();
        var button3 = new Button();
        button1.Text = "Play";
        button1.Location = new Point(20, 100);
        button1.Click += new EventHandler(button1_Click);

        button2.Text = "Prev";
        button2.Location = new Point(110, 100);
        button2.Click += new EventHandler(button2_Click);

        button3.Text = "Next";
        button3.Location = new Point(200, 100);
        button3.Click += new EventHandler(button3_Click);

         this.Controls.Add(button1);
         this.Controls.Add(button2);
         this.Controls.Add(button3);
        }


        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            keybd_event(VK_MEDIA_PLAY_PAUSE, 0, KEYEVENTF_EXTENTEDKEY, IntPtr.Zero);
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            keybd_event(VK_MEDIA_PREV_TRACK, 0, KEYEVENTF_EXTENTEDKEY, IntPtr.Zero);
        }

        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            keybd_event(VK_MEDIA_NEXT_TRACK, 0, KEYEVENTF_EXTENTEDKEY, IntPtr.Zero);
        }
    }
}

'@  -ReferencedAssemblies System.Windows.Forms, System.Drawing  


$player = [UniversalSandbox.Form1]::new()
$player.ShowDialog()
```

Answer (score 0):

[Mike Twc's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60133794/45375) shows an effective solution that adds many pieces that were missing from your code.

As for **what you tried** in terms of **syntax**:

> `[UniversalSandbox.Form1]::button1_Click`

tries to access a *static* (`::`) *public* member named `button1_Click`.

If there *were* such a *method* (there isn't, because (a) you've made it an *instance* method and (b) you've made it private), accessing it *without parentheses* `()` (including required arguments) would *print the method's signature* (its return type, name, parameter names and types) rather than *call* it.